# Why is my Administrator name always changing to "zeus"?

Tags: virus, user-accounts, malware, spybot-sd, bots

On Windows 7, my Administrator account is changing the name from time to time to "zeus" and the password also is being reset.

I've installed and cleaned my PC with a few malware removers (Ad-Aware, Spybot, Trojan Remover, HiJackThis, Rubotted, Kaspersky, Security Essentials).

How I can keep this from happening? I think there must be some script that is changing the username. I tried to search on logon scripts and startup scripts but is clean.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do a clean reinstall.

Comment: Maybe even run dban on the drive before re-installing...

Comment: Clearly, you haven't been keeping current on your quota of burnt offerings.

Comment: yep, i think will have to format this thing, thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

If your machine is truly compromised and malware cleaners arent fixing the issue, the safest thing to do is back up your data and wipe the machine.

Comment: You would have to be careful when backing up, because you may end up backing up the compromised data.

Comment: OP should be ok as long as it isn't executable data.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the only change occurring? Is it changing at regular intervals after you change it back?

My guess is that, assuming there are no scripts, is that someone may be hacking your machine.

Also, it looks like you have two anti-virus solutions installed simultaneously (Kapersky and Microsoft Security Essentials). While you can have multiple on-demand spyware scanners installed, having multiple virus scanners installed is a bad idea, so I would recommend deleting one of them, and then rescan your computer with the latest definitions.